# How do trees absorb carbon dioxide?

Tags: plants, carbon-sequestration

How much of carbon dioxide is used in the first years of the tree, and how much in maturity? How much goes in the soil, and how much in the wood? What about the night?

I live in northern Italy, and a list of trees present in my territory are listed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Trees_of_Europe).

I'd like to maximise absorption of carbon and pollution in the first years, and I'm also interested in the best performance of soil carbon sequestration, as it is seems to be more efficient (i.e. carbon is stored for much more time than wood).

Comment: This question is old, but if you're still looking for an answer, it might be a better fit on [biology.SE](https://biology.stackexchange.com/). I'm voting to close in the meantime.